# Sails + ReactJS : Unexpected token, can't find why

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, reactjs, sails.js

I'm working on a Sails JS application and i try to use React in it. I'm new to both React and Sails since a few days.
I tried it with a "simple" example, i have a list of user, and i want to display a list of them using React.
I have a method "getUsers" in "MainController" that return the users object. When i go to "main/getUsers" on the browser i get :

```
   {
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "username": "User1",
      "password": "sha1$e89ea270$1$5937f3d94f90280e3dc5a435bd8c8128f9d29ab2",
      "mail": "test@mail.fr",
      "pics": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-02-29T12:58:46.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-02-29T12:58:46.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "username": "test",
      "password": "sha1$88a41992$1$f43d52da22e2082a06625063e36c4a965451094f",
      "mail": "test@hotmail.fr",
      "pics": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-02-29T12:23:57.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-02-29T13:05:42.000Z"
    },
    (...)
  ]
}
```

my code to display them is the following :

```
<div id="example">test</div>

<script type="text/babel">
    var User = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            <p class='oneUserList col-xs-3 col-md-1'>
                <img src="{this.props.pics} />
                {this.props.username}
            </p>
        }
    });

    var UserList = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function () {
            return {users: []};
        },
        componentDidMount: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/main/getUsers/",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false
            }).exec(function (response) {
                this.setState({users: response.records });
            }.bind(this));
        },
        render: function () {
            var self = this;

            var users = this.state.users.map(function (p) {
                return <User username={p.username} pics = {p.pics} />
            });

            if (!users.length) {
                users = <p>Loading users ..</p>;
            }

            return (
                {users}
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <UserList />,
        document.getElementById("example")
    );
</script>
```

I tried it many ways but i always have the same error :
"SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (x:y)"
right now it's on the space before 'url: "/main/getUsers"' but if was on the a of ajax, then on the r of url ..etc and i really don't understand why

If somebody could help me with this,
thanks

Comment: You sure it's not choking on the JSX? The "unexpected token" error usually crops up when there's a missing JSX parser

Answer (score 0):

Your JSX syntax was not correct. I tested this by copying your code into https://babeljs.io/repl/.  Specifically, in your `User` component, you have:

```
<img src="{this.props.pics} />
```

You need to remove the double quote from that line.

Comment: It was that, seriously .. >< Thank you